# Мониторинг качества данных в Airflow

Tags: python, apache, airflow

появилась задача мониторить качество поступающих из источников данных в Airflow. Собрались писать своё решение, но интересно есть ли какие-то нативные для Airflow, или стандартизированные инструменты для решения этой задачи которые могут сильно упростить жизнь.

Необходимый минимум заключается в том чтобы отправлять уведомления на почту или в telegram при базовых сценариях ошибок при которых таски не падают: пришла пустая таблица, типы данных до обработки несоответствуют первоначальной схеме но преобразуются, столбцы имеют пропуски там где это не ожидается

Идеально если в будущем к этому можно будет накрутить уведомление об экстремальных выбросах в конкретных метриках, может быть несоответствие регулярным выражениям в конкретных столбцах.

Подскажите в какую сторону копать? Может это можно сделать с помощью самого Airflow или каких-то инструментов Apache?

P.S. Airflow висит на собственном железе внутри докер-контейнера

Answer (score 0):

Есть фреймворк для мониторинга качества [Greate Expectations](https://docs.greatexpectations.io)
Можно попробовать интегрировать, есть [примеры](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-great-expectations/)